# Next.js global CSS animations

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, css-animations

I have a Next.js (13.3.0) project. 
I have an issue with a global style that includes animations. 
Here is my folders structure: 
[image]

So I load all the scss files by the **master.scss** file:

```
@import './all.css';
@import './animations.scss';
@import './big-flag.scss';
@import './coat.scss';
@import './flags16-both.scss';
@import './flags16-extra.scss';
@import './flags32-both.scss';
@import './flags32-extra.scss';
@import './locations.scss';
@import './index.scss';
```

Inside the **animations.scss** files I have the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }

    8% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
        transform: rotate(12deg);
    }

    10% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    18% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    20% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    28% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    30% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    38% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    48% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    58% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    60% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    68% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-12deg);
        transform: rotate(-12deg);
    }

    8% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);
        transform: rotate(12deg);
    }

    10% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    18% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    20% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    28% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    30% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    38% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    48% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    58% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    60% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
        transform: rotate(-24deg);
    }

    68% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(24deg);
        transform: rotate(24deg);
    }

    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

I load the **master.scss** file in the **pages/_app.js** file:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import '../assert/css/master.scss';
import store from '../store/store';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Now, all the global styling is working as expected, but whenever I want to use "shake" animation, it doesn't work.
It's not throwing any errors, but it just doesn't work. 
The only way for it to work is to declare it in a specific scss file of the component.
Is there any way to solve this issue without duplicating the code for each component?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add the :global selector to the class where you wanted the globally scooped animation. Hope it helps!

```css
component scooped styles file/module
.someClassToAnimate {
  &:global {
    animation: shake 200ms ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of duplicate code in my project, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes and my self as well :D